# -bash: eas: command not found on mac

Tags: reactjs, expo, command-line-interface, eas

After successfully installing eas cli using `npm install -g eas-cli`.
When I type `eas` on terminal it shows `command not found`.

```bash
$ npm install -g eas-cli

$ eas
-bash: eas: command not found
```

Comment: Run `npm config get prefix`, and make sure that your environment `PATH` variable includes `{prefix}/bin`.